# The oven in my range has stopped heating up, but the burners still work

Tags: oven, natural-gas, range

The oven recently stopped getting hot, but the burners still work fine.  **Any ideas about what might be wrong?**

Here's the kind of stove I have: [Hotpoint® 30" Free-Standing Gas Range](http://products.geappliances.com/appliance/gea-specs/RGB745WEHWW)

Here's what I tried so far:

1. I checked the circuit breaker.  The circuit wasn't tripped and I flipped it on and off again just in case. No effect.
2. The manual said to check the shut off valve under the stove.  I think it's on, but I can't be sure.  Here's what I see:

   [image: Picture of what I think is the shut off valve under the stove]

Comment: Is the oven electrically heated? If so, there are several possible causes.

Comment: Does the oven use gas only,  electric  only, or a little of both?   Gas only ovens have no plug whatsoever.

Comment: A little of both.  It cooks the food with gas and the electronics use electricity.  I don't know if it has an electric igniter or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is a recent model without a pilot light. And by recent I mean not ancient. There will be an electric heating element that glows white hot to ignite the gas. It can burn out. You might actually be able to see it glow if you look hard while the oven is lighting if it is working. Then again it could be electrical or mechanical.

Comment: Had a repair guy come out and replace the heating element.  Oven is working like a champ again.  Thanks!

Comment: I guess I'd call that the "oven ignitor", as it doesn't heat the oven per se :)